# FB.Event.subscribe - none of the event gets triggered

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, xfbml

I am trying to include the facebook login/registration plugin in my web page. Whenever I click on login or click on logout the corresponding **FB.Event.subscribe** should be triggered. But in my case, the login and logout happens successfully. but none of those events get triggered.
Find below the code,

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
    FB.init({
        appId   : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        status  : true,
        cookie  : true,
        oauth   : true,
        xfbml   : true 
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        alert('You have successfully logged in, '+response.name+"!");
        });
    });     

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            alert('You have successfully logged out, '+response.name+"!");
        });
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    });
};

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

It would be great if anyone could help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Those events only trigger when the user status CHANGES.

For the `auth.login`, for example, this change happens when the user has not already authorized your page and then gives the authorization. In this first time, the user does not have the facebook cookies values for your page. When he or she authorizes your page, the cookie values will be written by the FB JS SDK and your script will sense the `auth.login` change event. Next time, when your user come back again, the cookie values should be already there, and the event will not trigger, because there's no CHANGE of the status.

The `auth.login` event triggers, also, when the user has already authorized your app, but cleaned up the cookies. In the next visit, the FB JS SDK will have to write the cookies again and the event will happens.

I'm not sure about the `auth.logout` event, because I do not use it, but as far I know, it does not have relation to your app, but with the session status of your user's facebook account.

I recommend you to monitor the cookie values changes on your page during the execution of your script to understand better when the events occur.